# Can we have more than 1 MPMoviePlayerController in single view?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I have the list of videos link `www.abc.com/videos/mvideo.m4v` format coming from server.

So if I get 3 links I have to display 3 videos in a screen and make it play/pause depending upon the button.

I have implemented it in `UITableView` Everything seems to be fine..

But the only issue I am facing is that If there are 3 MPMovieController allocated in a single view then only last one is working and rest both are not at all working.. just have a black Screen.

Same If there are 2 links then only the second one is working and other one is just having a blank screen with no controls.

**Note:** Allocation of Mpmovieplayer controller is done in cellForRowAtIndex method

Comment: You should check the documentation of MPMoviePlayerController - there is a specific passage saying something like: only one instance of MPMoviePlayerController may be active at a time.

Comment: @Till I have gone through the documene and it says `Although you can create multiple MPMoviePlayerController objects and present their views in your interface, only one movie player at a time can play its movie.` But if I create more than 1 instance none of them are accessible :( only the last one is playing vide and rest others are without controls and never plays video :(

Comment: Totally agree with you, Hakuna.  Basically it does not work at all if you try to have more than one on screen at the same time.  If I try "two" they both just go black.  Very annoying!